# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto en tipo int

Tags: asp.net, .net

Tengo un control textbox en cual se llama

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIdentificador" runat="server" placeholder="Identificador de Cliente" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>
```

Pero al momento de guardar en la base de datos me muestra el siguiente error:

```
La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.
```

En la siguiente Linea de código

```
int numregistro = Int32.Parse(txtNumregistro.Text);
```

Comment: Y en `txtNumregistro.Text` que pusiste como valor?

Comment: En el código haces referencia a `txtNumregistro` y muestras el tag para `txtIdentificador`. Por otro lado, no mencionas que valor tiene `txtNumregistro.Text` en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: El campo txtNumresgistro

<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumregistro" runat="server" placeholder="Número de registro" CssClass="field_auto"></asp:TextBox>